# Start WCF service application from another application (C#)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service application and a Windows forms application. I want to get some data from WCF, but it is started automatically only from IDE.

My question is simple: how can I start WCF service application from Windows forms application?

UPD: these 2 applications has different bitness, so the can't be hosted in the same process.

Comment: Is the Service installed? If so, what is its name?

Comment: take a look  at my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  can use [ServiceHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class
something like this

```
public static void Main()
{
  using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService)))
  {
    try
    {
      // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages.
      serviceHost.Open();

        // The service can now be accessed.
      Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
      Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
      Console.ReadLine();

      // Close the ServiceHost.
      serviceHost.Close();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException timeProblem)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(timeProblem.Message);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException commProblem)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(commProblem.Message);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

But you can adapt it to winforms  easily or if you want you can 
[Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If i call it from winforms application, service will be hosted in the same process, am I right?

Comment: And there's no way to avoid it? WCF service and winforms application has different bitness, so it won't run this way.

Comment: if you want you can use windows service to host your service